how to work with ora_rowscn pseudocolumn in PySpark JDBC
I am trying to read big oracle table using spark JDBC and transfer it to clickhouse.
    jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbschema", table_schema) \
    .option("dbtable", f'{table_schema}.{table_name}') \
    .option("driver", jdbcDriver) \
    .option("fetchsize", 150000) \
    .load()

    click_field_name = ['field1', 'field2']

    jdbcDF.select(*click_field_name, lit(run_id).alias("run_id")) \
    .write.format("jdbc") \
    .mode("append") \
    .option("url", jdbcClickUrl) \
    .option("user", login_click) \
    .option("dbschema", schema_click) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("password", pswd_click) \
    .option("truncate", "true") \
    .option("driver", jdbcClickDriver) \
    .save()

When trying to pass ora_rowscn in field list I get A column or function parameter with name ora_rowscn cannot be resolved.
Tried also to pass it through adding jdbcDF.withColumn("ora_rowscn", expr("ora_rowscn")).select...
but got the same. Are there any options to work with oracle pseudocolumns in pyspark in dbtable option mode?

Are you sure you want/need ora_rowscn ? As for your error, without knowing pyspark or whatever you're using on the client side, my guess is that it describes the table from the dictionary and knows which columns you can reference, and a pseudo-column wouldn't be one of them.

Yes, I am using ora_rowscn to determine changes in source table

be aware that you must turn on rowdependencies for that to work, and even then it won't tell you about deletes. The only sure way to find all changes is either to compare source with target in full (in two passes) or have a trigger that captures the I/U/D operation in a log table.

can't you use a select query instead of table name in spark to fetch what you need?
